# Google chrome npapi plug-in load support on Leopard (10.5.8)

Tags: google-chrome, npapi

Does Google Chrome loads npapi based plug-in on Leopard (10.5.8). My npapi based plug-in is loaded by Google Chrome on Snow Leopard (10.6) and Lion(10.7). But on Leopard (10.5.8) my plug-in is not loaded.

Do I have to make any change to make my plug-in work on Google Chrome on Leopard (10.5.8)?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, plugins were supported in Leopard; we have one we're using there.  If it isn't loading I would guess there are some incompatibilities with libraries or APIs that you're using.

Are you building it against the 10.5 SDK and setting the deployment target to 10.5?

Answer (score 0):

What drawing model(s) does your plugin use? If it's only Core Animation, then it won't work in Chrome on 10.5, as support for the Core Animation model (as opposed to the invalidating Core Animation model) is 10.6+ only.

It would help if you could be more specific about what you mean by "loaded". Does the plugin show up in chrome://plugin but not actually get instantiated, or is it not even listed?

Comment: My plug-in shows up in chrome://plugin. But when I open the page which loads my plug-in. It says "Missing Plug-in". My plug-in has two drawing models, 1. Core Animation 2. Core Graphics. We load Core Animation drawing model on Google Chrome. What changes should I make to ensure that my plug-in works on Google Chrome on Leopard (10.5.8).

Comment: Read my answer to your other question, and learn about drawing model negotiation. The change you need to make is that you need to actually negotiate a drawing model with the browser instead of guessing what model you think you can use based on user agent. The whole point of the negotiation system is to avoid problems like yours.

Comment: My plug-in does negotiate with the browser regarding the model. But your suggestions are correct. I will take away the code for checking if my plug-in is loaded out of process. But I still have a question. Which drawing model does Chrome support on 10.5?

Comment: If you are unconditionally setting the model to CA in Chrome, then you aren't negotiating. Negotiating involves asking the browser which models it supports, *at runtime*, and then setting the model to one it supports. Chrome on 10.5 doesn't support CA (it supports everything else--which you could easily determine if you put a bit of logging into your plugin), and will answer as much if asked, so the fact that your plugin didn't work in Chrome on 10.5 is evidence that you were not, in fact, negotiating.